# How do I remove a misspelling I accidentally added to spell checker in Google Documents?

Tags: google-docs, spell-check

I misspelled a word and accidentally added it to the spell checker dictionary in Google Documents. How can I remove it?

When I google the problem I see many results and questions from 2010 and 2011, so I can't tell if it's been fixed since then or just never been fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Editing my post, Google just released the Personal Dictionary. Once I see documentation in the support files I will post.

In your Google Doc, go to Tools > Personal Dictionary and all of your spelling additions will be stored there. You will be able to add or remove custom words.

To add a word, right click the underlined word and select Add to personal Dictionary.

To remove the word, right click the word and select Remove from Personal Dictionary.

Again, this is brand new to Google Docs and once I have a support file I will post it here.